# passing and allocating pointer to void* in c

Tags: c, void-pointers, generic-programming

I have used function pointers in c to create a generic struct.
when i call a specific function, one of the parameters is an output parameter. I allocate the memory inside the specific function but it doesn't work. would love some help!

```
typedef void *PhaseDetails;
typedef Result (*Register)(const char *, PhaseDetails *);

Result Func(const char *file, Register register1){
    PhaseDetails firstPhase = NULL;
    Result res = register1(file, &firstPhase);
}

int main() {
    OlympicSport os = Func("men100mList.txt", (Register) registerMen100m);
    return 0;
}

Result registerMen100m(const char *file,
    Men100mPhaseDetails *firstPhase) {
    firstPhase = malloc(sizeof(*firstPhase));
    if (firstPhase == NULL) {
        return OG_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_FAILED;
    }
    *firstPhase = malloc(sizeof(**firstPhase));
    (*firstPhase)->phaseName = malloc(sizeof(char)*12);
    return OG_SUCCESS;
}
```

the problem is that the `firstPhase` returns as `NULL`

Comment: You're never calling `Func`. Should that be `Result osCreate`?

Comment: Because the parameter is passed by value (or copy if you prefer), then it is not modified by the function (function modifies its copy). Add another level of indirection. (Note that most of your code is wrong, bad function calls, types, etc).

Comment: what do you mean by "Add another level of indirection"?

Comment: The function argument should be `PhaseDetails *firstPhase`. Then it should do `*firstPhase = malloc(sizeof(Men100mPhaseDetails))`

Comment: Why do you have two `malloc()` calls in the function? The second one is correct. But the argument type is wrong, it should be `PhaseDetails*` to match the `Result` typedef.

Comment: You can't use `sizeof(**firstPhase)` because `void` doesn't have a size.

Comment: The code invokes UB when doing `Result res = register1(file, &firstPhase);` as `register1` had been initialise (using the casting hammer) to a function of different type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you pass a pointer to `firstPhase` (defined in `Func()`) into the `firstPhase` argument of the `registerMen100m()` function but, as first thing in the function, you overwrite it with the address of a freshly allocated memory block.

After that the value of `firstPhase` in the `Func()` function is not, and can not, be changed from within `registerMen100m()`

```
Result registerMen100m(const char *file, Men100mPhaseDetails *firstPhase)
{
  /* At this point, firstPhase holds the address of the variable
  ** 'firstPhase' you defined in the 'Func()' function.
  */
  firstPhase = malloc(sizeof(*firstPhase));
  /* And now it doesnt! So you will never be able to get anything back
  */

  if (firstPhase == NULL) {return OG_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_FAILED;}

  /* The result of the following malloc is stored in the memory space you
  ** allocated earlier! If you remove the two lines above you 
  ** should most probably get what you wanted.
  */
  *firstPhase = malloc(sizeof(**firstPhase));
  (*firstPhase)->phaseName = malloc(sizeof(char)*12);
  return OG_SUCCESS;
}
```

As a general remark using the same name around makes sense only if it means the samething everywhere. Here you have `firstPhase` with two different meaning in two different functions and this makes difficult to reason about what's happening.
Also, passing functions as arguments is something you very rarely need. Is there any specific reason why you structured the program this way?